# Why is linalg.norm faster than sum of squares for 1-d numpy arrays, but not 2-d arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Ok, this might be a bit esoteric, but I was investigating the relative merits of numpy.linalg.norm(X) vs numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(X**2)).

When I threw a n*d matrix into these two functions and calculated an array of sum of squares along one axis, I was surprised to find that the sqrt/sum/** combo worked (very slightly) faster than linalg.norm().
However I found with subsequent testing that linalg.norm() is solidly faster when doing sum of squares on a single array.

Here is some test code and output (I use a custom timeit() function; don't worry about it):

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

def timeit(func, iters, name):
   startTime = datetime.now() 
   for i in range(iters):
       func()
   print(name, datetime.now() - startTime)

print('100*1000, 100 loops')

timeit(lambda *a: np.linalg.norm(np.random.rand(100,1000), axis=1), 100, 'linalg')
timeit(lambda *a: np.sqrt(np.sum(np.random.rand(100,1000)**2, axis=1)), 100, 'sumosq')

print('100, 10000 loops')

timeit(lambda *a: np.linalg.norm(np.random.rand(100)), 10000, 'linalg')
timeit(lambda *a: np.sqrt(np.sum(np.random.rand(100)**2)), 10000, 'sumosq')
```

And output:

```
100*1000, 100 loops
linalg 0:00:00.484933
sumosq 0:00:00.482585
100, 10000 loops
linalg 0:00:00.332493
sumosq 0:00:00.394401
```

This pattern was replicated every time. Why is linalg.norm less efficient, relatively, on the matrix compared to the array?

Comment: Where `norm` is faster it is uses `sqrt(dot(x,x))`. Where it times the same it uses a variant on the `sqrt(sum(x*x, axis=1))` approach.  It is harder the adjust for `axis` and dimensions with the `dot` approach.